# Get text from PHP echo and update DIV using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm learning HTML, PHP, AJAX and jQuery in my degree. In a practise I need to refresh a DIV container every 3 seconds without recharging the whole page.

I must use AJAX to refresh and the response need to be a random number generated in the server using PHP.

I have this:

**index.php**

```
<div id="contador">NEED TO OVERWRITE THIS TEXT</div>
```

**number.php**

```
<?php
    echo "Number: " . rand(1,100);
?>
```

**ajaxreload.js**

```
function update() {
  $("#contador").load('Loading...'); 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'number.php',
    timeout: 3000,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#contador").html(data);
      $("#contador").html(''); 
      window.setTimeout(update, 3000);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $("#contador").html('Timeout...');
      window.setTimeout(update, 3000);
    }
});
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    update();
});
```

The DIV is being updated each 3 seconds, but it isn't getting the echo response from number.php. I'm getting a very fast "Loading..." message and then "Timeout...". What is wrong? I need to use another thing instead of echo? Another type or URL data? Another AJAX function?

Thank you!

**SOLVED**: Thank you! Solved in the console :) The problem is that my index.php file are in the root and the number.php and ajaxreload.js in a "scripts" folder. The parameter url: 'number.php' try to load it from the div location (where index.php is) and not where script file is calling

Thank you @dan08 @Keith Chason 
It was the first time I use the console

Comment: What does your console say?  I mean do you get the php response? Also why do you set the div and then reset it to null?

Comment: `$("#contador").html(''); ` You're emptying the contents right after you set it. Also, if you're getting into the error handler, it would make sense to actually check what error is being reported.

Comment: I copy this line from other user question. But deleting this line still getting "Timeout" @PatrickQ

Comment: If I load this PHP file in my browser, I'm getting the answer. But I think it isn't getting the response in the AJAX script @Akintunde

Comment: 1. Check your console (network tab) to see how the ajax request is doing (it is failing somehow). 2. Add a `console.log(textStatus)` in the error function to get more information about the error.
Please add the results to your question.

Comment: Thank you! Solved in the console :) The problem is that my index.php file are in the root and the number.php and ajaxreload.js in a "scripts" folder. The parameter url: 'number.php' try to load it from the div location (where index.php is) and not where script file is calling @dan08

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an environment in which to test this right now, but my suspicion is that the `window.setTimeout(update, 3000);` is not what you're meaning to do.

The `timeout` parameter of the `$.ajax` function is the amount of permitted time for the request, not the interval in which it runs.

http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-method

If you're trying to have it load every 3 seconds, I'd do use the `setInterval` function in Javascript:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
function update() {
  $("#contador").load('Loading...'); 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'number.php',
    success: function(data) {
      $("#contador").html(data);
      //$("#contador").html(''); This clears your <div>
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $("#contador").html('Timeout...');
      console.log('TextStatus: '+textStatus);
      console.log('ErrorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(update, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still getting "Timeout..." using your code

Comment: That might have to do with what you're retrieving. I updated my answer with debugging values so look at the console on your browser and see if you're getting anything. Also, check to see that your `number.php` is accessible via the web browser.

Comment: Thank you! Solved in the console :) The problem is that my index.php file are in the root and the number.php and ajaxreload.js in a "scripts" folder. The parameter url: 'number.php' try to load it from the div location (where index.php is) and not where script file is calling

Comment: It will work using either technique, the difference being that setInterval gives a flat 3 seconds for update to run before calling it again, and setTimeout waits 3 seconds after the ajax request has resolved before calling it again.